# Nunit does not run the tests for a specific namespace in an assembly

Tags: .net, nunit, nunit-console

I have big assembly containing large number of tests. These tests are grouped under different namespaces. I tried running the test cases for a specific namespace from the nunit-console but no tests are run. This happens only for this assembly. It works in a sample test assembly i created for testing this.

What may be the reason? Is there any limitation?

The command line command i used is below

nunit-console.exe /noshadow /nothread /run:namespace Absolute_path_of_the_dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.10), I'd expect you to use the `/fixture` argument:

> The name specified after the /fixture option may be that of a TestFixture class, a legacy suite (using the Suite property ) or a namespace. If a namespace is given, then all fixtures under that namespace are run. This option may be used with Visual Studio or NUnit projects as well.

So

```
nunit-console /noshadow /nothread /fixture:Foo.Bar.Baz PathToAssembly.dll
```